# How to store output into a column of csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have scraped some links using the following code, but I can't seem to store them in one column of excel. When I use the code it will parse all the alphabet of the link address and will store them in multiple columns.

```
for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', class_="title entry-title"):
    print(h1.find("a")['href'])
```

This yields all the links I need to find.

To store in csv I used:

```
import csv
with open('links1.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', class_="title entry-title"):
        writer.writerow(h1.find("a")['href'])
```

I also tried to store the results for instance using

```
for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', class_="title entry-title"):
    dat = h1.find("a")['href']
```

and then tried using `dat` in other csv codes but would not work.

Comment: what do you mean by store in one column. Like one link every line?

Comment: pandas dataframe may make things a lot easier

Comment: @Bobby yes, one link every line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need one link every line, You may not even need a csv writer? It looks like plain file writing to me

The new line character should serve you well at one link per line

```
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', class_="title entry-title"):
        f.write(str(h1.find("a")['href']) + '\n')
```

Comment: yea, I originally wanted to get csv as output, but I guess I can do this and then import to excel.

Comment: @song0089 There is nothing magical about csv, just name your file as xxx.csv. If you have more than one column in a row, add commas. This is farily simple for now. If the data get complicated I will say check out pandas